# Turning int array into a char before String

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, int

For the function below

```
public static String symbolArrayToString(int[] symbols) { 

  String message = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {

        symbols[i] = message.codePointAt(i)-65;
        message = message + Integer.toString(symbols[i]);

        message.toUpperCase();

    }
    System.out.println(message);

    return message; 
}
```

How would you convert the int array to chars before it becomes a String? I keep on either getting this error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.codePointAt(Unknown Source)
    at Caesar.symbolArrayToString(Caesar.java:50)
    at Caesar.main(Caesar.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at   edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand
      (JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Or it just returns the numbers of the array in a String.

Comment: `message` is empty. but you are trying `message.codePointAt(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the character by using this :

`Character.toChars(symbols[i])`

So your code should be like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        message = message + String.valueOf(Character.toChars(symbols[i]));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line with .codePointAt to work with the array itself. Try this:

```
public static String symbolArrayToString(int[] symbols) { 

String message = "";

for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {

    symbols[i] = symbols[i] - 65;
    message = message + Integer.toString(symbols[i]);

    message.toUpperCase();

}
System.out.println(message);

return message;
```

}